# Smallest lattice containing a poset

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-property

Given a poset $P$(we can assume $P$ is finite if necessary), how can we construct the smallest lattice containing $P$? (Does this exist?) To make the question precise, I am looking for a lattice $L$ and an order-preserving inclusion $\iota : P \to L$ which satisfies the following universal property:

If $L'$ is a lattice and if $f : P \hookrightarrow L' $ is an order-preserving injection, then there exists a unique lattice morphism $\varphi : L \to L'$ such that $\varphi \circ \iota = f$

Comment: The answer is "no" as you've written it even if $P$ is the just the poset with $2$ incomparable elements - but the answer is "yes" if you change $\varphi$ from being merely order-preserving to being an actual lattice morphism (i.e. preserves meets and joins). I'm not sure which is more of interest in an answer.

Comment: This was actually what I meant!

Comment: Note that your universal property really describes the _largest_ lattice that is generated by $P$.  It is smallest only in that it is generated by $P$ and doesn't have unrelated extraneous elements.  However, typically the morphism $\varphi$ in the universal property will be far from injective and so $L'$ may actually be much smaller than $L$.

Comment: The universal property seemed to me like the universal property of the groupification and/or sheafification and/or fraction field. This is why I called it the smallest lattice containing P. But you are right. This the smallest in the sense that it is generated by $P$ and there are no unrelated joins or meets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - but it is incredibly difficult to describe explicitly.

First, the really general way to do this is to use the fact that lattices are algebraic structures and to basically write a presentation of the lattice you want, then just compose the universal properties of freeness and quotients. In particular, if $(P,\leq)$ is your poset, you can consider the free lattice on $P$ modded out by the relation $a \vee b = b$ for each pair $a\leq b$ in $P$. Call that lattice $L$.

There is then an obvious order-preserving map $\iota:P\rightarrow L$ which has the universal property that for any $f:P\rightarrow L'$ into another lattice, there is a unique lattice morphism $\varphi:L\rightarrow L'$ such that $f=\varphi\circ \iota$. You can check that $\iota$ is actually injective by using this universal property on the map $f$ taking $P$ into the powerset of $P$ by the rule
$$f(x)=\{z\in P: x\geq z\}$$
and noting that this $f$ is injective, so $\iota$ must also be.

Unfortunately, this brings us to the bad news: It is hard to describe even what a free lattice on three elements looks like (it is, for one thing, [infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382773/free-lattice-in-three-generators)) - but, of course, if we apply this construction to a poset on three incomparable elements, that's exactly what we get. All this construction says is "the lattice consists of the set of expressions using the operations $\vee$ and $\wedge$ on terms which are either themselves expressions or terms from $P$ modulo an equivalence relation generated by the lattice axioms and the relations $a\vee b \sim b$."

There's also another nice general construction that somehow feels even less explicit, but is a bit easier to verify without any prior knowledge:

> Let $P$ be a poset and $S$ be a sufficiently large set*. Let $F$ be the set of all tuples $(\vee, \wedge, \iota)$ such that $(S,\vee,\wedge)$ is a lattice and $\iota:P\rightarrow S$ is an order preserving map into $(S,\vee,\wedge)$. Then, consider the lattice
> $$\mathscr L = \prod_{(\vee, \wedge, \iota)\in F}(S,\vee,\wedge)$$
> and the map $\iota : P\rightarrow\mathscr L$ given by the product of the maps $\iota$ to each factor. The lattice generated by the image of $\iota$ satisfies the universal property.

(*Any set at least as large as every lattice generated by a set of size $|P|$ would suffice; assuming the axiom of choice, this means "countable" when $P$ is finite, and just "equally large as $P$" when $P$ is infinite)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [Dedekind–MacNeille completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion). To paraphrase [Theorem 5.3.8](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ordered_Sets/2esoXnolEWgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA119) in the book Ordered Sets by Bernd Schroeder, the Dedekind–MacNeille completion is the **smallest complete lattice** $L$ containing $P$, i.e. there is an embedding $\iota : P \to L$ and for any other complete lattice $L'$ with an embedding $f : P \to L'$ there is an embedding $\phi : L \to L'$ such that $f = \phi \circ \iota$. Since every finite lattice is complete, for finite lattices the Dedekind–MacNeille completion is simply the smallest lattice.

"Embedding" refers to an [order embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_embedding), an injective function for which $a \leq b$ iff $f(a) \leq f(b)$, i.e. it is both order-preserving and order-reflecting. So compared to your precise question it is a stronger notion than the "order-preserving injection" but weaker than the lattice (homo)morphism. But the Dedekind–MacNeille completion of $P$ does preserve all joins and meets of $P$.